# Regex to detect back slashes, numbers and special characters in a query string

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

Today must either be a very bad day for me finding an answer on Stack Overflow or even Google and boy I have really scoured for an answer to this.

I have noted some IP's sending query strings like this to Nginx

**\xB1\xF2\x08\xF5lN;\x15T-\x06\x03N**

Note these are all back slashes \ not the usual / forward slashes used in urls. Also note the special characters they send along with all of that.

My problem is trying to find a regex that will match a query string pattern like that no matter how long it is. I have seen some that were 10 times longer than this.

Nginx of course responds with a 400 error so that's not a worry but I would like to detect this behavior and have a rewrite or something else happen when it is detected.

Hope someone can help. My regex is rusty at the best of times and my head is all messed up with the flu today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
[\\\w+\d+\;\-]+
```

https://regex101.com/r/zD2oH8/1

Comment: That is brilliant, take a bow. I don't how you did that so quick but I guess when you can think in regex you can write it fluently. I must really sit down and learn my way around and I will start with this very example and study it thoroughly.

I just added **^** in front of your regex and it picked up on a test string on that site exactly where that pattern began and matched the whole pattern. See I already learned something. Thanks a million !!!

Comment: Your welcome :) If you want start learning regex - start with this: http://regexone.com/. You'll solve it 2-3 times then, stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex and practicing. It's not difficult:)
Thanks for good word, and good luck!